# RestKit key existence in stractured objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

**Hello guys,**

I want to map my complex JSON structure that pulled from my server with the RestKit.

Here is the JSON structure example:

```
"_cat0": [
    {
        "title": "category header",
        "catId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 542232,
        "title": "post post",
        "time": "1421744040"
    },
    {
        "id": 542232,
        "title": "post post",
        "time": "1421744040"
    },
    {
        "id": 542232,
        "title": "post post",
        "time": "1421744040"
    }
],
```

As you can see here, we have an head object that represents the category of each section. The `"_cat0"` actually is a prefix that contains the full data of each category in the JSON. This prefix is continuable and contains everything inside, that means: posts, category data and more parameters.

The first object at each category contains the title and the category-id

```
{
        "title": "category header",
        "catId": 1
    }
```

And the other objects contains the posts of the category.

My problem with RestKit is to find the Post object and the Category object by the values in the JSON.

I thought about finding unique key inside the head object and store it as a category object and then any other objects in the JSON stored as a Post. But I didn't found any functions that can help me with the key existence or check if the key of the object is nullable.

Here is my try for this issue:

```
if ([representation containsValueForKey:@"catId"]) {
        // it's a category object
        return categoryMapping;
    } else {
        // it's a post object
        return postMapping;
    }
```

But this code crashes after the run.

Any ideas for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you need help debugging a crash, please post the crash stack trace and error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have assigned the JSON array to an object named `_cat0`, you could do the following:

```
for (NSDictionary *object in _cat0) {
  if ([[object allKeys] contains:@"catId"]) {
    // Process object as category metadata.
  } else {
    // Process object as a post.
  }
}
```

---

If you have control over the JSON response, I *strongly* recommend that you make its structure more meaningful. Something along the lines of:

```
"_cat0": {
    "title": "category header",
    "catId": 1
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 542232,
            "title": "post post",
            "time": "1421744040"
        },
        {
            "id": 542232,
            "title": "post post",
            "time": "1421744040"
        },
        {
            "id": 542232,
            "title": "post post",
            "time": "1421744040"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Actually as Ian said, this JSON structure more meaningful. Then the fetching and mapping of the JSON with RestKit is more easy.

Comment: @Ian so i have changed the JSON structure, do you have a tutorial for the right way?